# Flexslider 2.0 with Animate.css for captions

Tags: jquery, flexslider, animate.css

I am trying to integrate animate.css for caption in flexslider but didn't get a success yet. Can any expert help me to do that.

Thanks
-Shak

Answer (score 3):

I know this can be done using data attributes, have a look at my fiddle, although with this example I used jquery.cycle2.

```
.caption1 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
background:#000;
font-size:27px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:30;
padding:5px;
-moz-animation: fadeInRight 1 ease-in 1.3s backwards; -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1s ease-in 1s backwards; animation: fadeInRight 1s ease-in 1s backwards;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps a bit. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/npqB5/)